# Extend codeigniter reactor models

Tags: codeigniter, php

How to extend Codeigniter Reactor (2.0.2) Models in the older versions all what you have to do is to create MY_Model class in the libraries folder but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

just solved the problem, I had to make the MY_Model class inside application/core